# Need an algorithm to choose the most appropriate numbers from a set to satisfy an increasing value

Tags: algorithms

Given a set of relatively random numbers (example): `{125, 375, 100, 280, 900, 670, ...}`

I want to identify the numbers that most closely sum up to a set such as: `{400, 450, 500, 550, 600, 650, ...}`, while going over the target as little as possible.

In the example above we might get: `[400->{280, 125}, 450->{375, 100}, 500->{670}, 550->{900}]`

The ideal goal would be to limit total excess to a minimum and stop at a point where the overage exceeds an arbitrary threshold, such as say 10%.

What approach might I use here to come up with a good solution?

Comment: are you looking for an approximate solution or an exact solution? Note that this problem is an NP-Complete problem since you can easily reduce the subset sum problem to this problem.

Comment: You mean just sort the set of random numbers and just sum then until you reach each target value right? This occurred to me but seems to produce noon optimal results. I'm trying to identify as many sets of numbers as possible with the least overage possible.

Comment: Another algorithm that occurred to me was taking the highest valued number that is below my target, subtracting it from my target and repeating until I get just over my target. This gives decent results, but I wonder if more optimal is possible. I wonder if I could complete more sets for my target values, within my threshold, with another approach.